# primary key column isn't autoincrmenting in sqlalchemy (IntegrityError)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy model and a method to add a few elements to a table.  Here is the model and function:

```
class Roles(alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64), unique = True)
    default = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Boolean, default = False, index = True)
    permissions = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer)
    users = alchemyDB.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role $r>'%self.name

    @staticmethod
    def setRolesInDB(app):
        '''
            sets the basic roles in the database
        '''
        roles = {
                 'User' : (Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES, True),
                 'Moderator' : (Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES | Permission.MODERATE_COMMENTS, False),
                 'Administrator' : (0xff, False)
                 }
        with app.app_context():
            with alchemyDB.session.no_autoflush:
                for r in roles :
                    role = Roles.query.filter_by(name = r).first()            
                    if role == None :
                        role = Roles(name = r)
                    role.permissions = roles[r][0]
                    role.default = roles[r][1]
                    alchemyDB.session.add(role)
                alchemyDB.session.commit()


class User(UserMixin, alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_email = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    user_name = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    user_pass = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(128))
    role_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    communities = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64))
    articles_compared = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64))
    date_joined = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.DateTime)
    user_tags =  alchemyDB.relationship('UsersAppliedTags',
                                        foreign_keys = [UsersAppliedTags.user_id],
                                        backref = alchemyDB.backref('users_who_have_used_this_tag_for_this_article', lazy ='joined'),
                                        lazy = 'dynamic',
                                        cascade = 'all, delete-orphan')
```

Here is how I call the function :

```
alchemyDB.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
        # Extensions like Flask-SQLAlchemy now know what the "current" app
        # is while within this block. Therefore, you can now run........
    alchemyDB.create_all()
Roles.setRolesInDB(app)
```

I get the following error :

> ```
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
> ```
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) roles.id may not be
>   NULL u'INSER T INTO roles (name, "default", permissions) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?)' ('Moderator', 0, 1 2)

This table is just like any other and I have never had a problem where the primary key suddenly wasn't autoincremented.  What might be going wrong here?

As per a request, here is what the table looks like in the database:

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(Roles);
0|id|VARCHAR(64)|1||1
1|name|VARCHAR(64)|0||0
2|default|BOOLEAN|0||0
3|permissions|INTEGER|0||0
```

Comment: Show **direct** table structure (in database)

Comment: Tomasz, do you mean show all my tables in my post?

Comment: No, only roles table

Comment: I added a table info for the roles table.  I think I changed the model from having a string primary key (which was a mistake) to an integer.  If you see that this is the mistake, please post and I will mark as the answer.

Comment: Tomasz, I found the problem and your request directed me right to it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change type of `id` column to `INTEGER` and make it `autoincrement`.